# Why does FFMPEG SSIM produce different comparison results depending on which of these uncompressed videos goes first/second?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg's ssim instructions say the reference should go second, and when I compare these videos in that order, (where 'copy.avi' should be lossless H.264 copy of 'original.avi') SSIM and PSNR return lossless results. But if I reverse the order the performance isn't lossless.

Why is this happening?

### Copy first, original second

```
> ffmpeg -hide_banner -i copy.avi -i original.avi -lavfi "ssim;[0:v][1:v]psnr" -f null –


[avi @ 0x7ffdee002000] decoding for stream 0 failed
Input #0, avi, from 'copy.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 644937 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 2048x1536, 645930 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 120 tbc
Input #1, avi, from 'original.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.35.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1509965 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (Y800 / 0x30303859), gray, 2048x1536, 1512312 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> ssim:main
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> psnr:main
  Stream #1:0 (rawvideo) -> ssim:reference
  Stream #1:0 (rawvideo) -> psnr:reference
  ssim -> Stream #0:0 (wrapped_avframe)
  psnr -> Stream #0:1 (wrapped_avframe)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to '–':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p(progressive), 2048x1536, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 wrapped_avframe
    Stream #0:1: Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 2048x1536, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 wrapped_avframe
frame=  640 fps= 72 q=-0.0 Lq=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.66 bitrate=N/A speed=1.21x    
video:670kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_ssim_0 @ 0x7ffdef8024c0] SSIM Y:1.000000 (inf) U:1.000000 (inf) V:1.000000 (inf) All:1.000000 (inf)
[Parsed_psnr_1 @ 0x7ffdef802940] PSNR y:inf u:inf v:inf average:inf min:inf max:inf
```

### Original first, copy second

```
> ffmpeg -hide_banner -i original.avi -i copy.avi -lavfi "ssim;[0:v][1:v]psnr" -f null –


Input #0, avi, from 'original.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.35.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1509965 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y800 / 0x30303859), gray, 2048x1536, 1512312 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
[avi @ 0x7fb74680d600] decoding for stream 0 failed
Input #1, avi, from 'copy.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 644937 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 2048x1536, 645930 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 120 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (rawvideo) -> ssim:main
  Stream #0:0 (rawvideo) -> psnr:main
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> ssim:reference
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> psnr:reference
  ssim -> Stream #0:0 (wrapped_avframe)
  psnr -> Stream #0:1 (wrapped_avframe)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to '–':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: wrapped_avframe, gray(progressive), 2048x1536, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 wrapped_avframe
    Stream #0:1: Video: wrapped_avframe, gray, 2048x1536, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 wrapped_avframe
frame=  640 fps= 72 q=-0.0 Lq=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.66 bitrate=N/A speed=1.19x    
video:670kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_ssim_0 @ 0x7fb748101780] SSIM Y:0.998296 (27.684975) All:0.998296 (27.684975)
[Parsed_psnr_1 @ 0x7fb748101c40] PSNR y:56.840774 average:56.840774 min:56.812125 max:56.871584
```

Comment: two things stand out:
1) `[avi @ 0x7ffdee002000] decoding for stream 0 failed` even though the process completed
2) copy.avi has a tbc of 120 vs. 60 for original.avi (I don't know the implications of this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One format is yuv420p and another is gray. So for comparing them, one either convert gray to yuv420p or yuv420p to gray. As you noticed this operation is not always lossless. To compare only Y plane use extractplanes=y filter before calling psnr/ssim.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: I just ran this with "extractplanes=y" for the yuv420p video before psnr/ssim and it still didn't achieve 1.0 etc. Saying that, perhaps I should just trust that using SSIM/PSNR the right way round does produce the expected lossless result...

Comment: SSIM is symmetrical so as long as formats are same, result should be identical.

Comment: Strangely, I got reversed results - first original, then copy, and SSIM is 1. Both formats are yuv420p.